# При старте пк проблемы с микрофоном

Tags: linux, kde, kubuntu

Столкнулся с проблемой. Когда запускаю пк ничего не видит микрофон, но если его переподключить (кабель) то все работает. Меня замонало его выдергивать и вдергивать, пожалуйста подскажите что сделать, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: микрофон аналоговый или usb?

Comment: В параметрах звука тоже нет микрофона при старте?

Comment: KoVadim мини джэк

Comment: eri вроде нету.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем, кто уделил внемание моему вопросу. Я нашел ответ: я игрался с изменением звука и изменил нстройку с "аналаговый аудио дуплекс" на "аналоговый аудио выход"!